# Microsoft SQL code not working when converted to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a block of Microsoft SQL code that I am trying to get to work in MySQL (MariaDB 5.5.68). I have tried what feels like a thousand ways to make it work to no avail.

```sql
    SELECT t.title_id, t.title_name, p.pub_name,
    select a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname from authors a
    join title_authors ta on a.au_id = ta.au_id
    where ta.au_order = 1 and ta.title_id = t.title_id)
    as author_1, isnull ((
    select a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname from authors a
    join title_authors ta on a.au_id = ta.au id
    where ta.au_order = 2 and ta.title_id = t.title_id), '')
    as author_2, isnull((
    select a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname from authors a
    join title_authors ta on a.au_id = ta.au_id
    where ta.au_order = 3 and ta.title_id = t.title_id), '')
    as author_3 from titles t
    join publishers p
    on p.pub_id = t.pub_id;
```

Please help!

```
SELECT t.title_id, t.title_name, p.pub_name,
    (SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, ' ', a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 1 and ta.au_id = t.title_id) as author_1,
    ISNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 2 and ta.au_id = t.title_id),'') as author_2,
    ISNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 3 and ta.au_id = t.title_id),'') as author_3
FROM titles t
JOIN publishers p
ON p.pub_id = t.pub_id;
```

This spits out a table with NULL in the first column and nothing in the next two columns.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Those subqueries have a "smell" to them as well; why are you not using `JOIN`s or (probably better) a `JOIN` and conditional aggregation?

Comment: `ISNULL()` only takes one argument in MySQL, it returns true or false. I think you want `IFNULL()`.

Comment: What if a book has more than 3 authors?

Comment: @Larnu Sorry about that, I was on a different computer with no good access to the text. I have corrected that. Could you give me an example of the JOIN with conditional aggregation?

Comment: @Barmar In the dataset that we are using, only three authors exist.

Comment: Seems like an arbitrary limitation that might change in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ta.title_id = t.title_id?

Answer (score 0):

@JJ32 Had the answer. I was comparing two different columns. Here is the working code:

```
SELECT t.title_id, t.title_name, p.pub_name,
    (SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, ' ', a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 1 and ta.title_id = t.title_id) as author_1,
    IFNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 2 and ta.title_id = t.title_id),'') as author_2,
    IFNULL((
        SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, a.au_lname)
        from authors a
        JOIN title_authors ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
        WHERE ta.au_order = 3 and ta.title_id = t.title_id),'') as author_3
FROM titles t
JOIN publishers p
ON p.pub_id = t.pub_id;
```